# Windows-Media-Player UserAgent Causes Runtime Binding Exception ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-agent

Requests from Window Media Player user agents to our MVC4 site are causing the following exception in the view:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
>     at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>     at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
>     at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>     at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in _Layout.cshtml:line 6
>     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>     at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
>     at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

**User agents:**

- Windows-Media-Player/11.0.5721.5280
- Windows-Media-Player/10.00.00.4074

The request makes it through the controller action but fails when rendering the view.

I have tried setting my useragent to each of these and can reproduce the error. Unfortunately I can't determine what exactly is null.

I believe in the end it might be best to just block these agents as they don't seem to be valid users of the site but I want to try and fix the error first.